# Live TV recording .ts to mp4 with ffmpeg

Tags: video, ffmpeg, mp4

I am using HDHomrun Prime to record live TV, the resulted file is a .ts file.  I would like to convert this file into .mp4.  I tried VLC player to convert that that takes awhile.  My research shows that ffmpeg can do this but I ran into an error and google search for this is no help. I ran this code in terminal. (OS ubuntu 16.04)

```
ffmpeg -i gsgame.ts -c copy -bsf:a aac_adtstoasc ford_ffmpeg.mp4
```

and I get this.

```
[h264 @ 0x561db2eba2e0] SPS unavailable in decode_picture_timing
[h264 @ 0x561db2eba2e0] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0x561db2eba2e0] SPS unavailable in decode_picture_timing
[h264 @ 0x561db2eba2e0] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0x561db2eba2e0] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x561db2eba2e0] no frame!
[h264 @ 0x561db2eba2e0] SPS unavailable in decode_picture_timing
[h264 @ 0x561db2eba2e0] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0x561db2eba2e0] SPS unavailable in decode_picture_timing
[h264 @ 0x561db2eba2e0] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0x561db2eba2e0] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x561db2eba2e0] no frame!
[h264 @ 0x561db2eba2e0] SPS unavailable in decode_picture_timing
[h264 @ 0x561db2eba2e0] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0x561db2eba2e0] SPS unavailable in decode_picture_timing
[h264 @ 0x561db2eba2e0] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0x561db2eba2e0] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x561db2eba2e0] no frame!
[h264 @ 0x561db2eba2e0] SPS unavailable in decode_picture_timing
[h264 @ 0x561db2eba2e0] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0x561db2eba2e0] SPS unavailable in decode_picture_timing
[h264 @ 0x561db2eba2e0] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0x561db2eba2e0] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x561db2eba2e0] no frame!
[h264 @ 0x561db2eba2e0] SPS unavailable in decode_picture_timing
[h264 @ 0x561db2eba2e0] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0x561db2eba2e0] SPS unavailable in decode_picture_timing
[h264 @ 0x561db2eba2e0] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0x561db2eba2e0] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x561db2eba2e0] no frame!
[h264 @ 0x561db2eba2e0] SPS unavailable in decode_picture_timing
[h264 @ 0x561db2eba2e0] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0x561db2eba2e0] SPS unavailable in decode_picture_timing
[h264 @ 0x561db2eba2e0] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0x561db2eba2e0] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x561db2eba2e0] no frame!
[h264 @ 0x561db2eba2e0] SPS unavailable in decode_picture_timing
[h264 @ 0x561db2eba2e0] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0x561db2eba2e0] SPS unavailable in decode_picture_timing
[h264 @ 0x561db2eba2e0] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0x561db2eba2e0] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x561db2eba2e0] no frame!
[h264 @ 0x561db2eba2e0] SPS unavailable in decode_picture_timing
[h264 @ 0x561db2eba2e0] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0x561db2eba2e0] SPS unavailable in decode_picture_timing
[h264 @ 0x561db2eba2e0] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0x561db2eba2e0] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x561db2eba2e0] no frame!
[h264 @ 0x561db2eba2e0] SPS unavailable in decode_picture_timing
[h264 @ 0x561db2eba2e0] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0x561db2eba2e0] SPS unavailable in decode_picture_timing
[h264 @ 0x561db2eba2e0] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0x561db2eba2e0] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x561db2eba2e0] no frame!
[h264 @ 0x561db2eba2e0] SPS unavailable in decode_picture_timing
[h264 @ 0x561db2eba2e0] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0x561db2eba2e0] SPS unavailable in decode_picture_timing
[h264 @ 0x561db2eba2e0] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0x561db2eba2e0] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x561db2eba2e0] no frame!
[h264 @ 0x561db2eba2e0] SPS unavailable in decode_picture_timing
[h264 @ 0x561db2eba2e0] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0x561db2eba2e0] SPS unavailable in decode_picture_timing
[h264 @ 0x561db2eba2e0] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0x561db2eba2e0] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x561db2eba2e0] no frame!
[h264 @ 0x561db2eba2e0] SPS unavailable in decode_picture_timing
[h264 @ 0x561db2eba2e0] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0x561db2eba2e0] SPS unavailable in decode_picture_timing
[h264 @ 0x561db2eba2e0] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0x561db2eba2e0] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x561db2eba2e0] no frame!
[h264 @ 0x561db2eba2e0] SPS unavailable in decode_picture_timing
[h264 @ 0x561db2eba2e0] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0x561db2eba2e0] SPS unavailable in decode_picture_timing
[h264 @ 0x561db2eba2e0] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0x561db2eba2e0] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x561db2eba2e0] no frame!
[h264 @ 0x561db2eba2e0] SPS unavailable in decode_picture_timing
[h264 @ 0x561db2eba2e0] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0x561db2eba2e0] SPS unavailable in decode_picture_timing
[h264 @ 0x561db2eba2e0] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0x561db2eba2e0] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x561db2eba2e0] no frame!
[h264 @ 0x561db2eba2e0] SPS unavailable in decode_picture_timing
[h264 @ 0x561db2eba2e0] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0x561db2eba2e0] SPS unavailable in decode_picture_timing
[h264 @ 0x561db2eba2e0] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0x561db2eba2e0] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x561db2eba2e0] no frame!
[h264 @ 0x561db2eba2e0] SPS unavailable in decode_picture_timing
[h264 @ 0x561db2eba2e0] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0x561db2eba2e0] SPS unavailable in decode_picture_timing
[h264 @ 0x561db2eba2e0] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0x561db2eba2e0] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x561db2eba2e0] no frame!
[h264 @ 0x561db2eba2e0] SPS unavailable in decode_picture_timing
[h264 @ 0x561db2eba2e0] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0x561db2eba2e0] SPS unavailable in decode_picture_timing
[h264 @ 0x561db2eba2e0] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0x561db2eba2e0] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x561db2eba2e0] no frame!
[h264 @ 0x561db2eba2e0] SPS unavailable in decode_picture_timing
[h264 @ 0x561db2eba2e0] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0x561db2eba2e0] SPS unavailable in decode_picture_timing
[h264 @ 0x561db2eba2e0] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0x561db2eba2e0] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x561db2eba2e0] no frame!
[h264 @ 0x561db2eba2e0] SPS unavailable in decode_picture_timing
[h264 @ 0x561db2eba2e0] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0x561db2eba2e0] SPS unavailable in decode_picture_timing
[h264 @ 0x561db2eba2e0] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0x561db2eba2e0] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x561db2eba2e0] no frame!
[h264 @ 0x561db2eba2e0] SPS unavailable in decode_picture_timing
[h264 @ 0x561db2eba2e0] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0x561db2eba2e0] SPS unavailable in decode_picture_timing
[h264 @ 0x561db2eba2e0] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0x561db2eba2e0] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x561db2eba2e0] no frame!
[h264 @ 0x561db2eba2e0] SPS unavailable in decode_picture_timing
[h264 @ 0x561db2eba2e0] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0x561db2eba2e0] SPS unavailable in decode_picture_timing
[h264 @ 0x561db2eba2e0] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0x561db2eba2e0] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x561db2eba2e0] no frame!
[h264 @ 0x561db2eba2e0] SPS unavailable in decode_picture_timing
[h264 @ 0x561db2eba2e0] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0x561db2eba2e0] SPS unavailable in decode_picture_timing
[h264 @ 0x561db2eba2e0] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0x561db2eba2e0] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x561db2eba2e0] no frame!
[h264 @ 0x561db2eba2e0] SPS unavailable in decode_picture_timing
[h264 @ 0x561db2eba2e0] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0x561db2eba2e0] SPS unavailable in decode_picture_timing
[h264 @ 0x561db2eba2e0] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0x561db2eba2e0] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x561db2eba2e0] no frame!
[h264 @ 0x561db2eba2e0] SPS unavailable in decode_picture_timing
[h264 @ 0x561db2eba2e0] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0x561db2eba2e0] SPS unavailable in decode_picture_timing
[h264 @ 0x561db2eba2e0] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0x561db2eba2e0] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x561db2eba2e0] no frame!
[h264 @ 0x561db2eba2e0] SPS unavailable in decode_picture_timing
[h264 @ 0x561db2eba2e0] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0x561db2eba2e0] SPS unavailable in decode_picture_timing
[h264 @ 0x561db2eba2e0] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0x561db2eba2e0] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x561db2eba2e0] no frame!
[h264 @ 0x561db2eba2e0] SPS unavailable in decode_picture_timing
[h264 @ 0x561db2eba2e0] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0x561db2eba2e0] SPS unavailable in decode_picture_timing
[h264 @ 0x561db2eba2e0] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0x561db2eba2e0] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x561db2eba2e0] no frame!
[h264 @ 0x561db2eba2e0] SPS unavailable in decode_picture_timing
[h264 @ 0x561db2eba2e0] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0x561db2eba2e0] SPS unavailable in decode_picture_timing
[h264 @ 0x561db2eba2e0] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0x561db2eba2e0] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x561db2eba2e0] no frame!
[h264 @ 0x561db2eba2e0] SPS unavailable in decode_picture_timing
[h264 @ 0x561db2eba2e0] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0x561db2eba2e0] SPS unavailable in decode_picture_timing
[h264 @ 0x561db2eba2e0] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0x561db2eba2e0] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x561db2eba2e0] no frame!
[h264 @ 0x561db2eba2e0] SPS unavailable in decode_picture_timing
[h264 @ 0x561db2eba2e0] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0x561db2eba2e0] SPS unavailable in decode_picture_timing
[h264 @ 0x561db2eba2e0] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0x561db2eba2e0] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x561db2eba2e0] no frame!
[h264 @ 0x561db2eba2e0] SPS unavailable in decode_picture_timing
[h264 @ 0x561db2eba2e0] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0x561db2eba2e0] SPS unavailable in decode_picture_timing
[h264 @ 0x561db2eba2e0] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0x561db2eba2e0] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x561db2eba2e0] no frame!
[h264 @ 0x561db2eba2e0] SPS unavailable in decode_picture_timing
[h264 @ 0x561db2eba2e0] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0x561db2eba2e0] SPS unavailable in decode_picture_timing
[h264 @ 0x561db2eba2e0] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0x561db2eba2e0] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x561db2eba2e0] no frame!
[h264 @ 0x561db2eba2e0] SPS unavailable in decode_picture_timing
[h264 @ 0x561db2eba2e0] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0x561db2eba2e0] SPS unavailable in decode_picture_timing
[h264 @ 0x561db2eba2e0] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0x561db2eba2e0] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x561db2eba2e0] no frame!
[h264 @ 0x561db2eba2e0] SPS unavailable in decode_picture_timing
[h264 @ 0x561db2eba2e0] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0x561db2eba2e0] SPS unavailable in decode_picture_timing
[h264 @ 0x561db2eba2e0] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0x561db2eba2e0] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x561db2eba2e0] no frame!
[h264 @ 0x561db2eba2e0] SPS unavailable in decode_picture_timing
[h264 @ 0x561db2eba2e0] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0x561db2eba2e0] SPS unavailable in decode_picture_timing
[h264 @ 0x561db2eba2e0] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0x561db2eba2e0] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x561db2eba2e0] no frame!
[h264 @ 0x561db2eba2e0] SPS unavailable in decode_picture_timing
[h264 @ 0x561db2eba2e0] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0x561db2eba2e0] SPS unavailable in decode_picture_timing
[h264 @ 0x561db2eba2e0] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0x561db2eba2e0] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x561db2eba2e0] no frame!
[h264 @ 0x561db2eba2e0] SPS unavailable in decode_picture_timing
[h264 @ 0x561db2eba2e0] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0x561db2eba2e0] SPS unavailable in decode_picture_timing
[h264 @ 0x561db2eba2e0] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0x561db2eba2e0] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x561db2eba2e0] no frame!
[h264 @ 0x561db2eba2e0] SPS unavailable in decode_picture_timing
[h264 @ 0x561db2eba2e0] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0x561db2eba2e0] SPS unavailable in decode_picture_timing
[h264 @ 0x561db2eba2e0] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0x561db2eba2e0] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x561db2eba2e0] no frame!
[h264 @ 0x561db2eba2e0] SPS unavailable in decode_picture_timing
[h264 @ 0x561db2eba2e0] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0x561db2eba2e0] SPS unavailable in decode_picture_timing
[h264 @ 0x561db2eba2e0] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0x561db2eba2e0] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x561db2eba2e0] no frame!
[h264 @ 0x561db2eba2e0] Increasing reorder buffer to 2
[mpegts @ 0x561db2eb57c0] start time for stream 3 is not set in estimate_timings_from_pts
[mpegts @ 0x561db2eb57c0] PES packet size mismatch
    Last message repeated 1 times
[mpegts @ 0x561db2eb57c0] Could not find codec parameters for stream 4 (Unknown: none (ETV1 / 0x31565445)): unknown codec
Consider increasing the value for the 'analyzeduration' and 'probesize' options
[mpegts @ 0x561db2eb57c0] Could not find codec parameters for stream 5 (Unknown: none (ETV1 / 0x31565445)): unknown codec
Consider increasing the value for the 'analyzeduration' and 'probesize' options
[mpegts @ 0x561db2eb57c0] Could not find codec parameters for stream 6 (Unknown: none ([192][0][0][0] / 0x00C0)): unknown codec
Consider increasing the value for the 'analyzeduration' and 'probesize' options
Input #0, mpegts, from 'gsgame.ts':
  Duration: 02:38:20.56, start: 14821.384111, bitrate: 3998 kb/s
  Program 3 
    Stream #0:0[0x1167]: Video: h264 (High) ([27][0][0][0] / 0x001B), yuv420p(progressive), 1280x720 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], Closed Captions, 59.94 fps, 59.94 tbr, 90k tbn, 119.88 tbc
    Stream #0:1[0x1168](eng): Audio: ac3 ([129][0][0][0] / 0x0081), 48000 Hz, 5.1(side), fltp, 384 kb/s
    Stream #0:2[0x1169](spa): Audio: ac3 ([129][0][0][0] / 0x0081), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 192 kb/s
    Stream #0:3[0x116a]: Data: scte_35
    Stream #0:4[0x116b]: Unknown: none (ETV1 / 0x31565445)
    Stream #0:5[0x116c]: Unknown: none (ETV1 / 0x31565445)
    Stream #0:6[0x116d]: Unknown: none ([192][0][0][0] / 0x00C0)
[AVBSFContext @ 0x561db2ebade0] Codec 'ac3' (86019) is not supported by the bitstream filter 'aac_adtstoasc'. Supported codecs are: aac (86018) 
Error initializing bitstream filter: aac_adtstoasc
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (copy)
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (copy)
    Last message repeated 1 times
```

I appreciate any help.

Comment: Try "ffmpeg -f mpeg2video -i inputfile outputfile.mp4" or use "-f mpegts". The -f switch forces the codec. If the input is another format then use that. ffprobe will give you the codecs used.

Comment: `[AVBSFContext @ 0x561db2ebade0] Codec 'ac3' (86019) is not supported by the bitstream filter 'aac_adtstoasc'. Supported codecs are: aac (86018) 
Error initializing bitstream filter: aac_adtstoasc` that's the issue here. You can't use this bitstream filter with ac3 audio

Comment: i tried search for that bitstream issue but i'm finding anything on it.  @AndreyTurkin can you advice?

Comment: @WLGfx : `-f` switch forces the specified demuxer. To the OP, drop the `-bsf:a aac_adtstoasc`.

Answer (score 3):

From what I see your stream has ac3 audio that means the `aac_adtstoasc` bitstream filter will not work.

Converting the video should be as easy as (although it might take a while, depending on your video):

```
ffmpeg -i gsgame.ts -c:v copy -c:a aac ford_ffmpeg.mp4
```

Comment: No need to re-encode the audio. FFmpeg supports muxing AC-3 into MP4.